# Couldn't connect to the server? Getting the below error.How to get rid of that error?

Tags: django, django-settings

Couldn't connect to the server. Getting the below error. How to get rid of this error?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
self.connect()
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 194, in connect
self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 168, in get_new_connection
connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 130, in connect
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection  
refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Comment: Did you check that you have the correct name, user, password, host, and port for your database under DATABASES in your settings.py file?

Comment: show your Database settings.

Comment: DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'mymdb',
        'USER': 'mymdb',
        'PASSWORD': 'development',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}